# Reverse Proxy SSL

Tags: tls, proxy, nginx

I am having trouble finding out if a potential server configuration is secure. I have a server running a nginx reverse proxy that is accessible from a public ip address on the ports 80 and 443. I then have a private network that is internal to the machine nginx is running on with a 172.17.%.% address that only the machine can access. They are linux containers.

Is it secure to do a ssl connection to the reverse proxy then regular http to the containers running on the 172.17.%.% network as it is internal to the machine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is as secure as the machine - which is probably to say "not very". But I don't believe the issue stems from doing just HTTP internally, that is fine. The problem comes from having a single, internet-facing machine that does everything.

So if you are happy with the security of the machine then you are fine. Any attacker would need to be able to run a process on the machine in order to sniff the traffic but then there are certainly other ways for an attacker who has that level of access to sniff out your data or indeed cause other mayhem.

Just remember that there is no such thing as a totally secure machine when connected to the Internet.

Comment: yeh thats good enough for me